# How to insert all data from datagridview to database table on button click in c#

Tags: c#

I want to insert all datagridview data into database table on button click

```
    private void cs_btnfinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StrQuery;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            StrQuery = "INSERT INTO tblmedisale VALUES ('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value + "', '" + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value) + "', '" + Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) + "')";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StrQuery, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("aaaa");
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What issue are you having exactly? Where does `con` come from? You don't need to open and close it on every iteration, just open it once before the loop and close it afterwards (use a `using`). Also, you're prone to SQL injection attacks and should use prepared statements instead.

Comment: What problems are you having? Also you should be using a parametrized  query to prevent SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void  inserttoDatagridview()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open()
                (foreach GridViewRow rw in DataGridView1.Rows)
                {
                    cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into tblEmp (empid,empname,empdesg,dob) values (" & rw.Cells(0).Value & ",'" & rw.Cells(1).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(2).Value & "','" & CDate(rw.Cells(3).Value.ToString()) & "') ", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }   
            finally
            {
                con.Close()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    myconn = New SqlConnection("server=DESKTOP-49GM42J;DATABASE=BAC Billing_System;Trusted_Connection=true")
  myconn.Open()

    For Each rw As DataGridViewRow In DataGridEffectData.Rows

        mycmd = New SqlCommand("insert into AllProducts (ProductID,ProductName,UnitPrice,ItemsLeft) values ('" & rw.Cells(0).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(1).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(2).Value & "','" & (rw.Cells(3).Value) & "') ", myconn)
        mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Next
    myconn.Close()
```

This is almost the same code done in vb.net.my problem is it creates a blank row below every time i use this command to insert a row of data into the database via a dataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Do a check for empty row in a gridview inside the loop before doing an insert :

```
Private void  inserttoDatagridview()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open()
                (foreach GridViewRow rw in DataGridView1.Rows)

if rw.Cells(0) <> Nothing then
                {
                    cmd = New SqlCommand("insert into tblEmp (empid,empname,empdesg,dob) values (" & rw.Cells(0).Value & ",'" & rw.Cells(1).Value & "','" & rw.Cells(2).Value & "','" & CDate(rw.Cells(3).Value.ToString()) & "') ", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

End If
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }   
        finally
        {
            con.Close()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        dt.Clear();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\HEAT_STORE\HEAT_STORE\bin\Debug\db.accdb");

        if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count> 0)
        {   //                                                                                                        //values                                                                                                         
            string sql = "insert into SLAB(DATE,SHIFT,HEAT_NO,THICK,WIDTH,LENGTH,PCS,ST_GRADE,LOCATION,OPTION,SLAB_NO)values(@DATE,@SHIFT,@HEAT_NO,@THICK,@WIDTH,@LENGTH,@PCS ,@ST_GRADE,@LOCATION,@OPTION,@SLAB_NO) ";//
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);

            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count -1; i++)
          {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SHIFT", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HEAT_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@THICK", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WIDTH", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LENGTH", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCS ", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ST_GRADE", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOCATION", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OPTION", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SLAB_NO", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString());


            }
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;  
            MessageBox.Show("SaccessFuly");


        }
    }
```